# Overcurrent Protection for COB Leds wired in parallel powered by Const Voltage Mean Well Driver

Tags: led, current-limiting, led-driver, cob

Roughly this is my current wiring diagram. [image: wiring diagram]

The Mean Well driver that I am using is the HLG-185H-36B.  Output 36v DC, max current 5.2A.  The Cobs are 36V and have a max operating current of 2.76A, however, I am running them at around ~1.44A (Max).  The Mean Well driver has the ability to adjust volt/current which I do have setup to a 100k ohm Linear POT.

What I am worried about is if a COB fails.  I'd like to add overcurrent protection at the nodes that I marked with (NODE#) so that no more than 1.7A-2A could be drawn.

I also am concerned about thermal runaway, details more here (there is a section that talks about it more in-depth) http://ledgardener.com/constant-current-vs-constant-voltage-drivers/

What are my options to protect the circuit so the COB LEDs don't overdraw current in either the event of 1 or more cobs failing and/or thermal runaway?  Thank you!

Comment: Where are the COB & driver links ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, the Mean Well driver you named is a constant current driver.

You shouldn't be driving LEDs in parallel from a constant current source.

You should have LEDs in series to reach the voltage range of the current source.  Since your COBs already have LEDs in series to make up 36V, you need one driver for each COB.

The named driver is overkill for a single COB, and driving the COBs in parallel is asking for trouble.  You've already discovered the problems, hence your question.

The correct thing to do would be to use a driver for each COB, and each driver matched to the current needed for each COB.  Doing otherwise is just looking for problems, and it will probably be  more expensive and still not do an adequate job if one of the COBs dies (or just loses contact for a moment.)

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUa4xm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Theory

In a nutshell, the theory behind this design of mine is that the Vf NTC changes increase current sharing are offset by the Vdrop from the fixed R. Normally One uses Rs =>ESR difference of all devices which is +/-25% (typ) but you may get <+/-1% from the same batch. The Rs now becomes a convenient current sense to ensure current is sharing.  Since power W LEDs are roughly Vf=3V ( could be more +0.6/-0.2V depending on source quality) The best are 2.85V. I calculated 12S12P array but it could be 14x14 or 10x10.  Then I take the ESR of 1 LED Pd_total/n and the symmetrical Array gives the same ESR. Based on extensive experience, ESR for a single power LED of 3V range has an ESR = 1/Pd(max) +/-25% typ. (est.) Thus 100W/144= 2/3W rating per chip in COB.  But this 100W requires CPU water cooling to keep junctions at 80'C for long life (50kh). Otherwise it won't last that long and burn out like a tungsten bulb.  Thermal match improves stability.

### Conclusion  ( Use Series )

Go with Meanwell driver with a Current source for 2.5A, with CPU ultra coolers and Series LEDs or your 1.5A driver with CPU coolers  or 2.76A driver with Water CPU cooler.

If you have dozens of these lights in the USA use the 240Vac option to stay below breaker current ratings.

[image]